# unable to bind data in angular with jhipster project

Tags: angular, typescript, jhipster

I have generated jhipster project.
I use several entities among them ContratEntity and VoitureEntity.

I used JDL STUDIO.

My problem is that i tried to add some modification in contrat-dialog.component.html.

As verification, I tried to show in console the value of my parameter, but It can't bind data.

> ERROR TypeError:_co.contrat.voiture is undefined

[contrat.component.html]

```
<form name="editForm" role="form" novalidate #editForm="ngForm">
...
<div class="form-group">
                    <label class="form-control-label" jhiTranslate="assistanceApp.voiture.immatriculation" for="field_immatriculation">Immatriculation</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="immatriculation" id="field_immatriculation" [(ngModel)]="contrat.voiture.immatriculation"
                         required pattern="\d{4}TU\d+" />
</div>
<button type="button"  class="btn btn-primary" 
(click)="addVoitureToContrat()" >
                    ADD
                </button>
</form>
```

[contrat.component.ts]

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Response } from '@angular/http';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { NgbActiveModal, NgbModalRef } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-
bootstrap';

import { JhiEventManager, JhiAlertService } from 'ng-jhipster';

import { Contrat } from './contrat.model';
import { ContratPopupService } from './contrat-popup.service';
import { ContratService } from './contrat.service';
import { Voiture, VoitureService } from '../voiture';
import { Assuree, AssureeService } from '../assuree';
import { RefPack, RefPackService } from '../ref-pack';
import { RefCompagnie, RefCompagnieService } from '../ref-compagnie';
import { VoiturePopupService } from '../voiture/voiture-
popup.service';
import { ResponseWrapper } from '../../shared';
import { RefMarque, RefMarqueService } from '../ref-marque';

@Component({
selector: 'jhi-contrat-dialog',
templateUrl: './contrat-dialog.component.html',
styleUrls: [
    'contrat-dialog.css'
]
})
export class ContratDialogComponent implements OnInit {

contrat: Contrat;

addVoitureToContrat()
{
  console.log(this.contrat.voiture);
}
```

[contrat.model.ts]

```
import { BaseEntity } from './../../shared';
import {Voiture} from '../voiture'
export class Contrat implements BaseEntity {
   constructor(
    public id?: number,
    public numero?: number,
    public debut?: any,
    public fin?: any,
    public voiture?: Voiture,
    public assure?: BaseEntity,
    public pack?: BaseEntity,
    public compagnie?: BaseEntity,
   ) {
   }
}
```

[voiture.model.ts]

```
  import { BaseEntity } from './../../shared';
  export class Voiture implements BaseEntity {
  constructor(
    public id?: number,
    public immatriculation?: string,
    public miseCirculation?: any,
    public puissanceFiscale?: number,
    public marque?: BaseEntity,
    public contrat?: BaseEntity,
   ) {
   }
```

}

I hope everything is clear.

Comment: Where and when is your *contrat* object assigned? Because it's missing from this piece of code + that's the exception. Either place the template piece in an `*ngIf` or assign the object in an `onInit`

Comment: there is full of code, I don't know exactly the process and how it works

Comment: I don't understand your comment. So you don't have a clue how Angular works and you cannot change the code?

Comment: jhipster generates full project all done.Changing some code seems to be hard

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you as I have no knowledge of jhipster. Try marking contrat or voiture as nullable in your tools. That might fix things.

Comment: what is the source of this error : _co.contrat.voiture is undefined.

Is it binding problem ?

Comment: No, it simply means your `contrat` variable is not assigned, so obviously it throws exceptions when using it.

Comment: have you verified in browser console that the JSON API returns embedded relationship? By default, all relationships are lazy loaded in JHipster JPA. So if you did not change the fetching on server side, it's very likely hat your JSON response does NOT embed the related objects. (leading to undefined) JHipster is not a tool for beginners, it requires some knowledge of the full stack: Angular, Typescript, Java , Spring MVC, Spring Security and JPA.

Comment: @Gaël Marziou It is an obligation for my work to use jhipster.

Comment: Then it's an obligation for you to train yourself enough on the technical stack that JHipster uses, if you don't do it you will fail on fist error encountered. Anyway have you tried what I suggested?

Comment: I am working on it

Comment: I faced this error with firefox navigator.
When I used chrome, it shows :   `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'immatriculation' of undefined`

Comment: @Gaël Marziou  I tried your suggestion but It does't work.

Comment: Yes, because `contrat.voiture` is undefined. Do you know the basics of object-oriented programming?

Comment: @NicoVanBelle yes,contrat.voiture is defined in contrat.model.ts

Comment: Defined, yes. Assigned, no!!

Comment: @NicoVanBelle What is your solution ?

Comment: Pretty much the same as @GaëlMarziou. Sharpen your knowledge of the tools and languages used by JHipster because you clearly fail to grasp the very basics required to fix the most simple of issues. Afterwards it should be clear to you what causes this error and what options you have to fix it.

Comment: Saying "I tried your suggestion but It does't work" is not very helpful because my suggestion was to collect information about the JSON in API response but you did not edit your question to paste it So how can I validate my assumption that the issue is on server while your question only shows only client code?